# Adding Conditional Validation Depending on Selected Actions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I need to add client-side scripting to perform data validation that depends on user selection in our OOP PHP page.

Consider the following:

```
<body>
    <form name="Contact" action="#" method="post">
        <label for="contName">Name:</label><input type="text" name="contName" /><br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_action" value="new">New<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_action" value="modify">Modify<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_action" value="deact">Deactivate<br/>
        <hr/>
        <label for="contStreet">Street:</label><input type="text" name="contStreet" /><br/>
        <label for="contState">State:</label><input type="text" name="contState" /><br/>
        <label for="contZip">Zip:</label><input type="text" name="contZip" /><br/>
        <label for="contUrl">Website:</label><input type="text" name="contUrl" /><br/>
        <hr/>
        <label for="contPref">Communication Preference:</label>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_Pref" value="phone">Phone<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_Pref" value="fax">FAX<br/>
        <input type="radio" name="rad_Pref" value="email">EMail<br/>
        <hr/>
        <label for="contPhone">Phone:</label><input type="tel" name="contPhone" /><br/>
        <label for="contFax">FAX:</label><input type="text" name="contFax" /><br/>
        <label for="contEmail">EMail:</label><input type="text" name="contEmail" /><br/>
        <hr/>
        <label for="contNum">Contact ID:</label><input type="text" name="contNum" /><br/>
        <label for="reqDate">Requested:</label><input type="text" name="reqDate" /><br/>
        <label for="reqBy">Requested By:</label><input type="text" name="reqBy" /><br/>
        <hr/>
        <input type="button" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

If a **NEW CONTACT** is selected from the `rad_action` Radio Button, the Contact Information is required.

Depending on the selected value of the `rad_Pref` Radio Button, either the **Phone**, **FAX**, or **EMail** would be required and validated.

This would be made much simpler if all of the contact data were housed in a central database, but our client has requested a form that will be converted to a PDF attachment, which will then be emailed to different departments, each with a database that has a different structure.

What's a good way to go about validating a form when a mix of items could be required and others could not be required?

I have been asked to create this routine as generic as possible so that the code (PHP and jQuery) can be reused in other online PDF creating forms. So, when a **Radio Button** is selected out of our PHP classes, we need a way to add in the javascript that it will be dependent on.

It sounds like I will need to add a method of passing in a bit of jquery to the objects themselves, but I don't know the best way of doing this so that the control is aware of other controls, too.

```
class HTML_RadioButton extends AbstractHtmlInput {

  public function AddValidation($validation) {
    // ???
  }

}
```

I have created a PHP Fiddle (**[php fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uv0-ghc)**), but there is currently no JavaScript or jQuery to validate anything.

Comment: http://theprogrammersparadox.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/myth-of-code-reuse.html

Comment: LOL - I hear ya! Not my company, though, so I don't get to make the rules.